# Can someone point me to really good NFC guidebook links and material online?

Tags: mobile, nfc

I am trying to understand this technology and need really good tutorial resources. The ones I have found are not detailed enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NFC has several modes: card reader/writer mode, card emulation mode and peer-to-peer mode. Furthermore, NFC in mobile devices makes use of particular data format: NDEF. Before you can properly understand the documentation of a particular NFC api (e.g. the Android NFC API), it makes sense to learn a bit more about the underlying technologies of NFC. A good starting point could be this tutorial: http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/wireless/nfc/near-field-communications-tutorial.php

An NFC API that is perhaps less relevant today is JSR 257. However, this tutorial provides a nice overview of NFC: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javame/nfc/

Answer (score 2):

There is an excellent book title **NFC From Theory to Practice** from WILEY.

Answer (score 1):

**Android**
Start [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html) or [here](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/wiki/GettingStartedAndroid).

1. If you want to explore the NDEF format, try this [Eclipse plugin](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/) for a graphical editor.
2. Try the [NDEF Tools for Android](http://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/downloads/detail?name=ndeftools-boilerplate-1.0.zip) boilerplate project.
3. If you learn by doing instead of reading, try this [workshop](https://github.com/skjolber/Fagmote/tree/master/Android/Near%20Field%20Communications).

The weak spot of many NFC tutorials on Android is that they use no high-levl API for reading and writing the NDEF content - this is where NDEF Tools for java comes to the rescue.

Comment: All of these are Android based tutorials? Can you please gimme link of some tutorial that talks about all platforms that support NFC? Like a really detailed tutorial? Thanks.

Comment: Yes they are all Android. NFC is a range of technologies, with different applications - se http://www.nfc-forum.org