# How to read specific sector of MIFARE CLASSIC 1K card

Tags: vb.net, smartcard, mifare

I'm complete novice with smart cards (yesterday i've started some research on the subject). What i need is to read 1 block of data where employee ID is stored.

I'm using MiFare NuGet package to achieve what i need.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MiFare

I was able to read UID and ATR code from the card, but when trying to read specific sector i get an error: "CardLoginException: Unable to login in sector 4 with key A or B" (I'm pretty sure that string key is ok).

What i have so far is

```
Public Class Form2

    Private WithEvents Reader As MiFare.Devices.SmartCardReader
    Private CardUid As String

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Ireader As MiFare.CardReader

        Dim ReaderList As New List(Of String)

        ReaderList = Ireader.GetReaderNames

        For i As Integer = 0 To ReaderList.Count - 1
            If InStr(ReaderList(i), "CL") > 0 Then
                Reader = MiFare.CardReader.FindAsync(ReaderList(i).ToString).Result
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End Sub


    Private Sub CardScan(Sender As Object, e As MiFare.Devices.CardAddedEventArgs) Handles Reader.CardAdded            
        Dim CardData As Byte()
        Dim CardKeyAs Byte()
        Dim HexString As String

        Const PKey As String = "XXXXXXXXX"

        Dim SkeyList As New List(Of MiFare.Classic.SectorKeySet)

        CardKey= MiFare.Classic.Extensions.StringToByteArray(PKey)

        Dim Skey As New MiFare.Classic.SectorKeySet
        With Skey
            .Key = CardKey
            .KeyType = MiFare.Classic.KeyType.KeyA
            .Sector = 4
        End With

        SkeyList.Add(Skey)

        Using MyCard As MiFare.Classic.MiFareCard = MiFare.Classic.FactoryMethods.CreateMiFareCard(e.SmartCard, SkeyList)

        CardData = MyCard.GetUid.Result
        CardUid = MiFare.Classic.Extensions.ByteArrayToString(CardData)
        Debug.Print(CardUid) 'this works fine 

            CardData = MyCard.GetData(4, 0, 8).Result ' Here is the error mentioned 
            HexString = MiFare.Classic.Extensions.ByteArrayToString(CardData)
            Debug.Print(HexString)
        End Using

    End Sub

End Class
```

**UPDATE**

This code is working on 
Identiv uTrust 3700 F CL Reader. Just got my hands on it. 
But it's not working on 
HID Global OMNIKEY 5422CL Smartcard Reader
Not sure why is that. I'll stick to new reader for now.

Comment: The reader dependency of APDUs for Mifare Classic is not exactly a surprise, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153173/standards-for-smartcard-communication).